# How to override $request query parameters in phpunit

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am modifying `subject_type` query parameter value inside the controller using `$request->merge`, it is working as expected while sending request using the browser or any API testing client. But the request query parameter cannot override in phpunit.

```php
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $request->merge(['filter' => ['subject_type' => 'new_value']]);

        return QueryBuilder::for(User::class)
            ->allowedFilters([AllowedFilter::exact('subject_type')])
            ->allowedSorts(['created_at'])
            ->defaultSort('-created_at')
            ->paginate($request->query('per_page', config('pagination.default.per_page_limit')));
    }
}
```

Here is my test case

```php
public function test_can_see_activity_log()
{
      $response = $this->getJson('/api/v1/users?filter[subject_type]=App\Models\Post');
}
```

Here I cannot override `subject_type` with `new_value`.

**Version**

```
"phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10"
"laravel/framework": "^9.19"
"spatie/laravel-query-builder": "^5.3",
```

Comment: Use dependency injection. Mock a request class and register it in the container.

Comment: @marius-ciclistu definitely DO NOT do that, NEVER EVER mock a request or a controller... check my profile on WHY not to do that...

Comment: Author, I am running a local test with your example, using `->get` and `->getJson` and it works flawlessly... you have to share your full test method, and please also try `->get` just to see if it works or it still fails. If it will not work with `->get` due to middleware, then add `$request->dump();` after the merge line and see what is the output when running the test

Comment: @matiaslauriti I was reffering to the assertion that merge is called.

Comment: @matiaslauriti are you able to override with supplied query param? In test case I am asserting the test case response data have length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `Spatie\QueryBuilder\QueryBuilder` not taking the new request. It has been fixed by `allowedFilters` callback.

```php
return QueryBuilder::for(User::class)
       ->allowedFilters([
               AllowedFilter::callback('subject_type', function ($q, $v) {
                  $q->where('subject_type', 'new_value');
               }),
        ]);
```

Comment: so, the issue was totally different to what you posted, how does this fix a test? how does it work on normal access but does not on a test?

Comment: I guess `$v` not getting the modified query parameter value. But the Callback solved my issue. Thank you @matiaslauriti for your effort.